# How to hear Twilio text to Voice again when press one

Tags: php, html, twilio

In my web application I have used Twilio application for automatic voice calling. Here I used Text to call using Twilio

```
<?php

header("content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
<Say voice='man'>Hello Welcome.</Say>
<Gather numDigits="1" method="POST">
<Say>
Press 1 to call again.
Press any other key to start over.
</Say>
</Gather>
</Response>
```

The Recipient will hear  "Hello Welcome" as voice. My question is how to hear again if he press 1 and also how to stop he press another digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

once the `<Gather>` completes, which in your case will be when the user presses one number on their keypad, Twilio is going to let you know that its done by make an HTTP request to a URL.  You can explicitly tell Twilio what URL to request by using the action parameter.

```
<Gather 
    action="http://example.com/yourpage.php" 
    method="POST"
    numDigits="1"
    timeout="10"></Gather>
```

In your case since you have not explicitly specified the action parameter, Twilio is just going to make a request back to the same URl that returned it the `<Gather>` verb.

When Twilio makes the HTTP request it will include a parameter named Digits that you can check:

```
$index = (int) $_REQUEST['Digits'];
```

Now you can use an `if` statement or a `switch` statement in your PHP to process change the behavior of your app based on the value of $index

In your case, that logic would look roughly like this in pseudocode:

```
if Digits does not exist OR digits exists and equals 1
    return welcome message TwiML
else
    either do nothing or explicitly return the <Hangup> verb
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you men on this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735957/twilio-calling-using-pure-php

Comment: Shall we set waiting time for response ?

Comment: Shall we set waiting time for response ? and can we set talking speed ?

Comment: You can configure how long the <Gather> attribute will wait for input by using the timeout attribute, which I added to the example in my answer.  There is currently no way to control the talking speed.  You can insert pauses into the text spoken to the reader by adding periods or commas.